# "if let" not unwrapping an optional value in Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, option-type

I am implementing **CoreML** in **Swift 4**, and here is an issue with `if let` that I am facing right now,

```
    var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
    var model: Inceptionv3?

    if let prediction = try? self.model?.prediction(image: pixelBuffer!)
    {
        classifier.text = "I think this is a \(String(describing: prediction.classLabel))." //ERROR..!!!
    }
```

> Value of optional type 'Inceptionv3Output?' not unwrapped; did you
>   mean to use '!' or '?'?

I know what the error means and how to resolve it. What I don't understand is why does it appear?

In the above code I am using `if let` to get an unwrapped value of `prediction`. And still it is asking me to unwrap it explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You are creating a doubly-wrapped optional because of the combination of *optional chaining* and the use of `try?`.  So, `if let` is only unwrapping the first layer of doubly-wrapped optional leaving you with an optional variable.

---

Why is this?

`try?` is used with a call that *throws*.  If the call does throw an error, the expression returns `nil`.  If the call succeeds, the value is wrapped in an *optional*.

You are using an *optional chain* to call `prediction` on `model`.  If model is `nil`, then the result of the optional chain is `nil`.  Note, this result didn't *throw* so the result gets wrapped in an *optional* by `try?` resulting in `Optional(nil)` which is not the same as `nil`.  If the call to prediction succeeds, the result gets wrapped in an *optional* because of the *optional chain*, and wrapped in an *optional* again because of the `try?`.

So there are three possible results:

1. Model is not `nil` and call to `prediction` returns a valid result of type `Inceptionv3Output` without throwing.  This result becomes `Inceptionv3Output?` because of the *optional chain* and `Inceptionv3Output??` because of the  `try?`.
2. Model is not `nil`, but the call to `prediction` throws an error.  The result of the `try?` is `nil` because of the throw.
3. Model is `nil`.  The result of the *optional chain* is `nil`, and that result gets wrapped in an *optional* again because of `try ?` resulting in `Optional(nil)`.

So, your `if let` is unwrapping a value of type `Inceptionv3Output??` which means `prediction` has the type `Inceptionv3Output?`.  The `if let` succeeds if the call doesn't throw.  If the `model` is `nil`, then `prediction` will be `nil`, otherwise it contains the wrapped value which is the result of the `prediction` call on the `model`.

Answer (score 0):

Try unwrapping it this way:

```
if  let model = model,
    let prediction = try? model.prediction(image:pixelBuffer!) {
    // Your code here
}
```

You can't use `try?` with an expression that doesn't `throw`. So you're forced to unwrap `model` just to make sure that the expression `throws`.

In case `model` was `nil`, the expression won't execute `prediction(image:)`, and this is why you're to unwrap `model` before using `try?`

Comment: But what is the need to do that if I am using optional chaining for that?

Comment: @PGDev I guess because you're using `try?` you need to make sure that there's code that might throw an error. So if you're using `self.model?.`, This code might not throw an error. So you're forced to unwrap the model before using `try?`.

Comment: How does using ? affects exception handling?

Comment: @PGDev The code that throws an error here is `prediction(image:)`, and if `model` was nil, it won't be executed. So you're getting the error because of that.